# Is there an algorithm to "club" nodes of a graph based on edge weight such that the total number of edges is minimized?

Tags: sequence, graph-theory

I'll explain myself better. I have a directed graph with nodes labelled 'a','b','c',etc. All outgoing edges from a given node have weights that add up to 1 (They are probabilities). I want to do the following:

1. If two nodes are joined by an edge with weight >0.8, they are "clubbed"
2. I want to do this in such a way that at the end, the number of edges of the graph are minimized, ie the clubbing configuration is such that there are as few edges in the resultant graph as possible.

Does the algorithm to do this already exist? In particular, I can figure out how to ensure that I have the least number of edges possible.

I already have an algorithm to do the "clubbing" part, but I had to give it a starting point, and it basically goes over every node from sequence a to z. I want to know if I can simply start at a random node and achieve this more efficiently, and if yes, how?

Comment: What does it mean to club vertices?  Please clarify, preferable with an example showing the process on a small graph.

Comment: "goes over every node "  Why?  Surely you need to loop over the edges, since you are looking for edges that have a weight > 0.8

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for weakly connected components of the graph made of all nodes in the original graph, and edges with weight > 0.8. Each component can then be considered a single node in the output graph. Note that strongly connected components can never be larger than 2 vertices. How are you handling the probabilities for edges between the merged vertices and other components?

Comment: "as few edges in the resultant graph as possible."  No matter where you start or how yo process the search, so long as the end points of every >0.8 weighted edge are 'clubbed' the resulting graph will be same.  What do you mean by 'as few edges as possible'?

Comment: Perhaps an example and a more rigorous definition of "clubbing" is in order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the algorithm

```
- Construct lCLUB, an empty list of vertex pairs 
- LOOP over edges
   - IF edge weight > 0.8 
      - ADD edge endpoints to lCLUB
- LOOP vp over LCLUB
    - CLUB the two vertices in vp
```

This still leaves the question of what it means to club vertices, which I asked 7 hours ago and still have received no answer.

In particular, what happens to this graph when it is "clubbed"

[image]

Comment: What if a vertex has both an incoming and an outgoing edge with weight greater than 0.8?

Comment: Sorry I didn't reply earlier, I posted this question during my working hours and today is a holiday at my place of work. By 'clubbing' I meant something like walking along those edges, collecting the nodes into a vector. Maybe a good way to explain this would be walking along a string hithisisdave and making strings like hi, this, is, dave

Comment: You talk of getting a "resultant" graph.  Collecting the the clubbed vertices into a new vector will give you the original graph plus a new vector - no resultant graph.